# Associative Array & XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, associative-array

I have an XML in this format:

```
<row typeID="5" volume="15" orders="6"/>
<row typeID="5" volume="2" orders="2"/>
<row typeID="6" volume="9" orders="5"/>
<row typeID="6" volume="8" orders="2"/>
<row typeID="1" volume="2" orders="2"/>
<row typeID="2" volume="162" orders="13"/>
```

I am using this:

```
$volumes = array();
foreach ($xml -> result -> rowset-> row as $row)
{
  $id = $row['typeID'];
  $volume = $row['volume'];
  $volumes[(string)$id] = $volumes[(string)$id] + $volume;
}
```

However I am getting this error on some of the ID's....

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 6
```

I don't understand that is the problem?.

This is what I am doing with the $volumes array:

```
while( $element = each( $volumes ) )
{
    $daily = $element['value'] / 10;            
    if ($daily > 30) {
        echo "typeid=" . $element[ 'key' ];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is an associative array, that is where the array is built..  It only gives this notice on particular ID's..  For instance 5 and 1 will work but 2 and 6 will throw a notice.  They are both present in the XML an data is being grabbed.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `$volumes[(string)$id] = $volumes[(string)$id] + $volume;`?

Comment: Where is `$volume` defined? It doesn't exist in your code snippet.

Comment: $volumes = array();  $volumes will contain the total amount of volume based on the typeID.  Eg.  typeID 6 will show 17 volume, typeID 2 will show 162 volume etc.

Comment: So, the first time an `$id` is encountered, it will throw a notice, because you are trying to read a value that does not exist yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you want to calculate the sum by id, using the code below, it will eliminate the warning.

```
<?php
$volumes = array();
foreach ($xml -> result -> rowset-> row as $row)
{
    $id = (string)$row['typeID'];
    $volume = $row['volume'];
    if (!isset($volumes[$id]))
    {
        $volumes[$id] = 0;
    }
    $volumes[$id] = $volumes[$id] + $volume;
}
```

I think you may need this to use `$volumes`:

```
foreach ($volumes as $id => $value)
{
    $daily = $value / 10;
    if ($daily > 30)
    {
        echo "typeid=" . $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that has solves the issue!.  I knew I needed to add !isset somewhere, but everywhere I tried just threw even more errors. I thought that the $volumes[$id] = $volumes[$id] + $volume; would basically translate to $volumes[$id] = 0 + $volume; but obviously not :)

Comment: I add some codes to the answer, hope would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to read non-existing key from your `$volumes` array triggers this notice. You try to read `$volumes[(string)$id]` before first assignment. Good practice is to use `isset()`:

```php
foreach ($xml -> result -> rowset-> row as $row) {
  $id = (string) $row['typeID'];
  $volume = $row['volume'];
  if (isset($volumes[$id])) {
    $volumes[$id] = $volumes[$id] + $volume;
  } else {
    $volumes[$id] = $volume;
  }
}
```

Quick-and-dirty approach is to disable notices: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`